# binary representation in turbo c

Tags: c++, c, turbo-c

I have a very basic query.
For the following code:

```
int i = -1;
unsigned int j = (unsigned int) i;
printf("%d",j); // I get 65535 the int limit in turbo C 16 bit compiler
```

Shouldn't it simply drop the negative sign or does it wrap around the limits ?

Comment: "does it wrap around the limits ?" Well I think you have the answer for your implementation already

Comment: @imsoconfused: this isn't implementation defined behavior - it's well specified in the standard. `(unsigned int) -1` will always be `65535` on a machine with 16-bit int regardless of whether the machine uses two's complement or not.

Comment: The behavior of this code is not defined by the C or C++ standards because the `%d` specifier requires an argument of type `int`, but the argument passed, `j`, has type `unsigned int`.

Comment: @MichaelBurr haha I wasn't sure, so I stuck with ambiguous wording that had to be correct and left the answer for better informed people

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The scheme most commonly used to represent negative numbers is called [Two's Complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement). In this scheme `-1` has the bit pattern of all `1` bits: `1111 1111 1111 1111`. When interpreted as an unsigned integer, which is what your cast means, that's 65535.

In other words, it does "simply drop the negative sign", except that doing so has a different effect than what you expect.

Comment: This does not explain the observed behavior. Passing `j`, which is an `unsigned int`, to `printf` for the `%d` specifier, which requires an `int`, does not have behavior defined by the C or C++ standards. Most implementations would print “-1” in this case, because the `unsigned int` is passed in the same place as an `int`, so `printf` receives the bits of an `unsigned int` but interprets them as an `int`. So how did “65535” result?

Comment: I hypothesize that the C implementation the OP is using passes 32-bit values for `unsigned int` and `int` parameters (even though those types are 16 bits) and that `printf`, when it is processing `%d`, uses the same code it does for `%ld`. Thus, what happens is that -1 is converted to `unsigned int`, producing 65535, and this is internally extended to 32 bits to be passed as a parameter. Then, in effect, `printf` receives the `long int` 65535 and formats it as “65535”.

Answer (score 1):

When converting an `int` to `unsigned int`, if the value is negative the result is as if that negative value has been added to the number one larger than what an `unsigned int` can hold. This is specified by the C standard since C90, and holds regardless of whether the machine uses two's complement, one's complement or signed magnitude representations.

Comment: This explains why `j` has the value 65535 but not why `printf("%d",j)` prints “65535”, since the wrong type has been passed for `%d`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: I hadn't noticed that. I suspect the question might not have the actual `printf()` code. Or maybe I don't really know what the whole deal is with Turbo C.

Comment: FWIW (not much) - I actually downloaded Turbo C 2.01 from Embarcadero and ran the code in the question.  It produced `-1` for me. Of course that's with whatever the default options are. Other options (memory model?) or other runs might do something else due to the nature of UB. Also, `printf("%u",j)` printed `65535` as expected. Why do schools still use Turbo C?